# php shell_exec: how to copy a directory from one user to another (VPS on CentOs5)

Tags: php, centos, vps, shell-exec

In Running on CentOS5 + DirectAdmin.

I own a VPS, but for security reasons I just want to give all managenent only to 'reseller' user.

With a resseler user I have script, which connects to ressellers DA and creates an user.

My problem is - how to copy a directory tree with ~10000 of files, which is located in '*resellers user*' ftp, ex. **/domains/hoster.dom.com/public_html/dir_to_be_copied**

to a new created user, which password and user name I know.

As i understand, it should be possible to do this as internal server action via 'shell_exec()' command.

Also, what is the command to login another user FTP and work with his files. And is it possible to be connected at the same time to the two FTP users, and make copies from one to another.

- I know that it may be suggested to do this logging as 'root' user, but maybe it is possible without accessing a 'root' user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
/**
 * Copy file or folder from source to destination, it can do
 * recursive copy as well and is very smart
 * It recursively creates the dest file or directory path if there weren't exists
 * Situtaions :
 * - Src:/home/test/file.txt ,Dst:/home/test/b ,Result:/home/test/b -> If source was file copy file.txt name with b as name to destination
 * - Src:/home/test/file.txt ,Dst:/home/test/b/ ,Result:/home/test/b/file.txt -> If source was file Creates b directory if does not exsits and copy file.txt into it
 * - Src:/home/test ,Dst:/home/ ,Result:/home/test/** -> If source was directory copy test directory and all of its content into dest     
 * - Src:/home/test/ ,Dst:/home/ ,Result:/home/**-> if source was direcotry copy its content to dest
 * - Src:/home/test ,Dst:/home/test2 ,Result:/home/test2/** -> if source was directoy copy it and its content to dest with test2 as name
 * - Src:/home/test/ ,Dst:/home/test2 ,Result:->/home/test2/** if source was directoy copy it and its content to dest with test2 as name
 * @todo
 *     - Should have rollback technique so it can undo the copy when it wasn't successful
 *  - Auto destination technique should be possible to turn off
 *  - Supporting callback function
 *  - May prevent some issues on shared enviroments : http://us3.php.net/umask
 * @param $source //file or folder
 * @param $dest ///file or folder
 * @param $options //folderPermission,filePermission
 * @return boolean
 */
function smartCopy($source, $dest, $options=array('folderPermission'=>0755,'filePermission'=>0755))
{
    $result=false;

    if (is_file($source)) {
        if ($dest[strlen($dest)-1]=='/') {
            if (!file_exists($dest)) {
                cmfcDirectory::makeAll($dest,$options['folderPermission'],true);
            }
            $__dest=$dest."/".basename($source);
        } else {
            $__dest=$dest;
        }
        $result=copy($source, $__dest);
        chmod($__dest,$options['filePermission']);

    } elseif(is_dir($source)) {
        if ($dest[strlen($dest)-1]=='/') {
            if ($source[strlen($source)-1]=='/') {
                //Copy only contents
            } else {
                //Change parent itself and its contents
                $dest=$dest.basename($source);
                @mkdir($dest);
                chmod($dest,$options['filePermission']);
            }
        } else {
            if ($source[strlen($source)-1]=='/') {
                //Copy parent directory with new name and all its content
                @mkdir($dest,$options['folderPermission']);
                chmod($dest,$options['filePermission']);
            } else {
                //Copy parent directory with new name and all its content
                @mkdir($dest,$options['folderPermission']);
                chmod($dest,$options['filePermission']);
            }
        }

        $dirHandle=opendir($source);
        while($file=readdir($dirHandle))
        {
            if($file!="." && $file!="..")
            {
                 if(!is_dir($source."/".$file)) {
                    $__dest=$dest."/".$file;
                } else {
                    $__dest=$dest."/".$file;
                }
                //echo "$source/$file ||| $__dest<br />";
                $result=smartCopy($source."/".$file, $__dest, $options);
            }
        }
        closedir($dirHandle);

    } else {
        $result=false;
    }
    return $result;
}
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php#91256

Comment: I know this is almost 4 years old now - but I have to tell you, all the other recursive copies I have tried were slow to move a wordpress setup. This thing - bam! Milliseconds and it's done. That's why I've +1'd it. Thanks Marco for a great function!